# What is the name and proof of the limit of this function?

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

In a proof I find the following limit being used:
$$ \lim\limits_{x \to \infty} (1- \frac{a}{x})^x = e^{(-a)}, $$

where $a$ is a constant. Does this limit have a common name and where can I find a proof (or please give a proof)?

Comment: It should be $e^{-a}$.

Comment: Thanks. It should also be exact not approx..

Comment: I think you should start from integer $x$ first. Because before defining $e^x$, $\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)^x$ is undefined for real $x$ in general. In other words, start from $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n=e^a$ first.

Comment: Technically this isn't a series or sequence even, just a limit.

Comment: @KitterCatter changed the question to limit of a function

Comment: What is your definition of $e^y$? $\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^n$ or $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{y^n}{n!}$. If you take the first one as the definition, then your limit follows from the definition and requires no proof.

Comment: @AlphaGo Now I see. So the formula is the definition of Euler's number (I was only familiar with the second representation you give). Wikipedia entry was illuminating https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant) However a proof of convergence is also not given there. Anywhays I feel more ready to accept this result now.

Comment: I don't know how clean you want to do this or how simple you want to do this but you might consider a change in variable y=-x/a. This makes your limit $[(1+1/y)^{-y}]^a$ which might be simpler to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

$$L=\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac{a}{x})^x$$

Now use:

$$\frac{d}{dx}e^x=e^x$$

To get if:

$$y=e^x$$

Then

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y$$

$$\int \frac{dy}{y}=\int dx$$

Define:

$$\int \frac{dy}{y} := \ln(y)+C$$

Then we have:

$$\ln (y)+c=x$$

Define:

$$\ln(e) :=1$$

If $y=e$ then $x=1$ and hence:

$$\ln (y)=x$$

$$\ln (e^x)=x$$

And,

$$e^{\ln (y)}=e^x=y$$

$$\ln (a^x)=\ln (e^{x \ln a})=x \ln a$$

Therefore,

$$\ln L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1-\frac{a}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}$$

Now take the derivative top and bottom using what what we have above and the chain rule.

Comment: I dont understand why you take such a complicated path because you can get your last equality $-a = \ln L=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln (1-\frac{a}{x})}{\frac{1}{x}}$ at once by taking logarithms of both sides of the initial identity :$ L=\lim_{x \to \infty} (1 - \frac{a}{x})^x$.

Comment: I was trying to show that if we define $\ln x$ as the antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\ln (e)=1$ then it follows that $\ln (e^x)=e^{ \ln x}=x$ . You use these identities to simplify to a L' hopital  form after you take the natural log on both sides. @JeanMarie

Comment: Let me make that more precise if $x>0$ then $e^{\ln x}=x$. Furthermore for every $x$: $\ln (e^x)=x$.

Comment: That's right, I use in a routine way the fact that : exp(ln(x))=x and ln(exp(x))=x ("exp" and "ln" are inverse one of the other)

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(1-\frac{a}{x}\right)^x$$
is not defined for general real $x$ yet before you defining $e^x$. So you need to define the function $e^y$ first.

If you define
$$e^y=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{y}{n}\right)^n$$
then
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{y}{n}\right)^n=e^{-y}$$
holds by definition and there is nothing to prove.

If you define
$$e^y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^n}{n!}$$
then you need to prove it. I cannot find a proof at the moment.

Here is a prove for the case $a=1$, to show that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$
Hope this may help:

Define
$$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n!}$$

Let
$$s_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{1}{k!}$$
and
$$t_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

By binomial theorem
$$t_n=1+1+\frac{1}{2!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{3!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{n!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{n-1}{n}\right)$$
Hence
$$t_n\le s_n$$
so that
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty}t_n\le e$$
Next if $n \ge m$,
$$t_n \ge 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)+\frac{1}{3!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)+\cdots+\frac{1}{m!}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1-\frac{2}{n}\right)\cdots\left(1-\frac{m-1}{n}\right)$$
Let $n \to \infty$, keeping $m$ fixed. We get
$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}t_n \ge 1+1+\frac{1}{2!}+\cdots+\frac{1}{m!}$$
so that
$$s_m \le \liminf_{n\to \infty}t_n$$
Letting $m\to \infty$ we finally get
$$e \le \liminf_{n\to \infty}t_n$$
Therefore,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e$$

Comment: You don't need $e^x$ to define $a^x$ for real $x$ and $a> 0$.

Comment: How to define it?

Comment: $a^x = \sup\{a^p:p\in \mathbb{Q}, p\leq x\}$.